# Expand numpy array of indices into a matix

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array of N integers ranging from 0 to M inclusive. I wish to treat them as indexes into an NxM matrix that contains a 1 in every position indicated by the array and a 0 everywhere else. For example, if given N=4, M=2 I have the following array

```
[1, 0, 2, 1]
```

I want to get this matrix

```
[0 1 0]
[1 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 1 0]
```

i.e. the row 0 has a one in column 1, row 1 has a 1 in column 0, etc.

How do I make this transformation in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires [multi-dimensional array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays).

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 2, 1])
z = np.zeros(12, dtype=int).reshape(4,3)
z[np.arange(a.size), a] = 1
```